# Split a list into sublists based on a condition with Stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a specific question. There are some similar questions but these are either with Python, not with Java, or the requirements are different even if the question sounds similar.

I have a list of values.

```
List1 = {10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99}
```

At the end of the day, I would like to split lists based on their values. I mean if the value is bigger than zero, it will be stay in the original list and the corresponding index in the negative values list will be set zero. If the value is smaller than zero, it will go to the negative values list and the negative values in the original list will be replaced with zero.

The resulting lists should be like that;

```
List1 = {10, 0, 23, 5, 0, 287, 5, 0}
List2 = {0, -2, 0, 0, -11, 0, 0, -99}
```

Is there any way to solve this with Stream api in Java?

Comment: You could use a `map` operation to map them to `Math.max(0, n)` and `Math.min(0, n)` respectively.

Comment: It would take two iterations with streams. You're better off with a single old-fashioned loop.

Comment: @jsheeran I have also thought of Map but the problem in my case that this operation will be executed in a for loop and the number of iteration will be decided on runtime. I prefer less operation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to do it in a single Stream operation, you need a custom collector:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99);

List<List<Integer>> result = list.stream().collect(
    () -> Arrays.asList(new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>()),
    (l,i) -> { l.get(0).add(Math.max(0, i)); l.get(1).add(Math.min(0, i)); },
    (a,b) -> { a.get(0).addAll(b.get(0)); a.get(1).addAll(b.get(1)); });

System.out.println(result.get(0));
System.out.println(result.get(1));
```

Answer (score 85):

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> results=
  List1.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy( n -> n < 0));
```

I think that this one is prettier and easy to read. (You can then get the negative and non-negative list from the map.)

Comment: But it doesn’t produce the zeros, the OP wanted.

Answer (score 13):

Since Java 12 it can be done very simple by using [`Collectors::teeing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
var divided = List.of(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                    Collectors.mapping(i -> Math.max(0, i), Collectors.toList()),
                    Collectors.mapping(i -> Math.min(0, i), Collectors.toList()),
                    List::of
            ));
```

Answer (score 7):

As shmosel already pointed out in the comments, you'll need two iterations using streams:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99);
List<Integer> positives = list.stream().map(i -> i < 0 ? 0 : i).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> negatives = list.stream().map(i -> i < 0 ? i : 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

All in one stream is possible if your list is modifiable. This is not better than a for-loop

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99);
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(i -> {
   int j;
   if ((j = list.get(i)) < 0) {
       list2.add(j);
       list.set(i, 0);
   } else {
       list2.add(0);
   }});
```

Comment: Is it not possible to edit the original list of the stream while creating a new list?

Comment: Very appropriate answer!!

Comment: You cannot modify a List while iterate over it, you'll a ConcurrentModificationException because then it won't be able to know on what he have to iterate if the list if changing

Comment: @azro but in this operation, the size of the list will not be changed if it is editted based on this condition. Only the value of the element will be changed. Will it throw still ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: @drJava As azro said above, that is a bad idea. Bit more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778017/modifying-objects-within-stream-in-java8-while-iterating)

Comment: @RobinTopper The answer of Pshemo means that it is possible to do it if the size of the list will not be changed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30778163/5873039

Comment: I really like the first solution, very elegant.

Comment: @Holger Any reason why `forEach` would be bettern than `count`? Just needed a terminal operation to evaluate the stream

Comment: @RobinTopper I think `count()` skips `map()` operations in Java 9. EDIT: Just noticed Holger said exactly that.

Comment: @Holger .... I'm clearly still waking up ... Of course I should have used `forEach`. Completely misinterpreted your first comment.

Comment: Note that the second approach, in its current form, is basically equivalent to a classic `for` loop.

Answer (score 6):

Java-Streams are a *functional programming* feature.

The essential pattern of functional programming is that you convert *one* collection to *one* other collection. This means your requirement is does not suit to a functional approach and hence java streams are the second best solution (after legacy for(each) loop).

---

**But**
Of cause you can split the problem into two separate FP friendly operations.

The downside it that this requires an additional loop over the input collection.
For small collections (up to roughly 100000 items) this may not be a problem but for bigger collections you may raise a performance issue.
<sup>**Disclaimer:** do not choose or deny an approach for performance reasons unless you have justified your decision by *measurement with a profiling tool*!</sup>

## conclusion:

I'd consider the "legacy loop" the better approach since it may be more readable in the sense that it better expresses your intent (to split up the collection).

Comment: Hmm, interesting point. What do you suggest me if I want to determine whether my problem suits the "functional approach" or not?

Comment: *"What do you suggest me if I want to determine whether my problem suits the "functional approach" or not? "* As I wrote in the answer: FP is applicable when you have an *unambiguous mapping* from one collection to another without looking at other items in the source or target collection.

Comment: I don’t see why functional programming should be limited to conversion of one collection to another. The two lists of the question are not different than a collection of pairs, semantically. There’s just less builtin support which makes a solution more complicated, [like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45007405/2711488), but there’s no fundamental difference to what `Collectors.toList()` does, it’s just two lists instead of one. That isn’t more or less functional than collecting into one list.

Comment: *"I don’t see why functional programming should be limited to conversion of one collection to another."* - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming : *"a style of building the structure and elements of computer programs, that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions and avoids changing-state and mutable data."* **mathematical functions** have *one* target collection only. But of cause: if you have a new hammer any problem looks like a nail...

Comment: I think your comment on functional programming is somewhat misleading. The "essential" pattern you describe is also wrong. The pattern is f(x) = y. Here x and y can be of completely different types. So x can be a list and y could be a list of list.

Comment: @TomasJansson *"The pattern is f(x) = y. Here x and y can be of completely different types. So x can be a list and y could be a list of list."* I can follow that reasonning but still feels a bit strange to artifically join the two desired result lists...

Comment: you could easily solve it with a reduce/fold operation where two lists are the input, then for each element you add the element to one of the lists.

Answer (score 6):

There are pros and cons in each solution.

- `for` loop is the obvious answer, but your question explicitly
  mentions Streams API.
- Using different predicates a) causes code duplication, b) is error prone, c) results in additional processing time — 2N
- Custom `Collector` is difficult to implement, and gives the impression of redundant work while the problem seems so straightforward, even naïve.

I haven't seen anyone else mentioning this, but you can collect your numbers in a `Map<Boolean,List<Integer>>` map, where key corresponds to your grouping criterion, and `List` is the selection of items matching the criterion, for example:

```
List<Integer> numbers = List.of(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99);
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> numbersByIsPositive = numbers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(number -> number >= 0));

List<Integer> positiveNumbers = numbersByIsPositive.get(true);
List<Integer> negativeNumbers = numbersByIsPositive.get(false);
```

Think of auto-boxing and -unboxing when applying this approach.

Output:

```
Positive numbers: [10, 23, 5, 287, 5]
Negative numbers: [-2, -11, -99]
```

Answer (score 5):

A generic solution without streams might consist of choosing between two possible consumers, based on a condition:

```
private static <T> Consumer<T> splitBy(
        Predicate<T> condition,
        Consumer<T> action1,
        Consumer<T> action2,
        T zero) {
    return n -> {
        if (condition.test(n)) {
            action1.accept(n);
            action2.accept(zero);
        } else {
            action1.accept(zero);
            action2.accept(n);
        }
    };
}
```

For your specific problem, you could use the `splitBy` method as follows:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99);

List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

list.forEach(splitBy(n -> n > 0, list1::add, list2::add, 0));

System.out.println(list1); // [10, 0, 23, 5, 0, 287, 5, 0]
System.out.println(list2); // [0, -2, 0, 0, -11, 0, 0, -99]
```

Answer (score 4):

Well you could do that in place:

```
  List<Integer> left = Arrays.asList(10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99);
    int[] right = new int[left.size()];

    IntStream.range(0, left.size())
            .filter(i -> left.get(i) < 0)
            .forEach(x -> {
                right[x] = left.get(x);
                left.set(x, 0);
            });
    System.out.println(left);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(right));
```

That is a side-effect, but as far as I can tell, it is a safe side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solutions for splitting the stream based on condition

Your List is List1 = {10, -2, 23, 5, -11, 287, 5, -99}

```
List1.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(num -> num <0))
```

This would give a Map with below key values

```
"true" : 10,24,5,287,5
"false": -2,-11,-99
```

Another solution is on the same line, but instead of using `partitioningBy`, use `groupingBy`

```
List2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(num -> num <0))
```