# How to replace a section of a string in document with another string while parsing a document

Tags: java, python, spring, string, pdf

I have a parsed PDF document that I parsed using a library in java.
The problem is that the tables in the document are not parsed properly, it is parsed like text(line by line). So I used a library in Python called Camelot that gave me the parsed table format and i sent this to java. I need to replace the PDF parsed tables with the one from Camelot and keep the remaining intact. There are multiple tables in a document and so the parsed tables return as a list of string with each index giving the parsed value of each table.

The `boundaryEND` tag represent the end of each table in the attached image of the Camelot Output.

I tried using streams by calling the `allmatch()` method but couldn't replace the section since `allmatch()` gives `boolean()` value (only indicates whether the strings match or not and not give the elements as such).[The output from the camelot is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7huN.png)

[Java parsed pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjaxn.png)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done via Stream APIs using custom collector. Check this link : [Split a list into sublists based on a condition with Stream api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006727/split-a-list-into-sublists-based-on-a-condition-with-stream-api)

Comment: That wont work since it splits a single list and i got two lists.