# Convert ArrayList<String> With Quotes Read from an external txt file to ArrayList<String> Without the Quotes Using Java 8

Tags: java

I am trying to read huge lines of words in quotes e.g "DSRD","KJHT","BFXXX","OUYTP" from a text file, so that I can have something like [DSRD, KJHT, BFXXX, OUYTP].

I have tried these 2 codes below but still returns the lines with quotes:

```
   1. List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath), ENCODING);
   2. List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath)));
```

Is there a way I can make this return just the list of the Strings without the quotes in each of the Strings?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just read it the way it is and take care of the quotes yourself? You can just take the quotes off and transform the text.

Comment: Is it expensive to apply regex on lines? Or you can modify when reading the file char by char.

Comment: I guess you could take the substring from 0 to `s.length() - 1` each time if you know that each string has quotes, but as Qunata said, you could just keep it the way it is and handle it later

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778017/modifying-objects-within-stream-in-java8-while-iterating

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the quotes after reading the file using `String#replaceAll` :

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath), ENCODING);
lines = lines.stream().map(s -> s.replaceAll("\"", "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wouldn't getting a substring be easier? replaceAll will go through the entire string

Comment: @user If he reads the whole file in a list, performance is probably not his problem. In doubt readability prior to performance optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words as they are separated by commas and apply transformation on them and finally join them back:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    String line = lines[i];
    String[] words = line.split(",");

    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        words[j] = words[j].replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
    }
    
    lines[i] = String.join(",", words);
}
```