# Any way to make this stream more efficient?

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach, java-stream

How would one optimise this without adding value into the new ArrayList instead just having the original list updated?

```
 String filterval = filter.toLowerCase();
 ArrayList<String> filtredArr = new ArrayList<String>();

                        listArray.forEach(
                                valueText -> {
                                        String val = valueText.toLowerCase();
                                    if (val.startsWith(filterval) || val.contains(filterval))
                                        filtredArr.add(valueText);
                                    else {
                                        Arrays.stream(valueText.split(" ")).forEach(
                                                singleWord -> {
                                                    String word = singleWord.toLowerCase();
                                                    if(word.startsWith(filterval) || word.contains(filterval))
                                                        filtredArr.add(valueText);
                                                }
                                        );
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30778017/6117426). In general it's not a good idea to modify the source of the stream while you're iterating over it, so creating a new list is better.

Comment: Optimise for what? Readability?

Comment: hmm instead of using foreach use some other terminal operation like filter() or?

Comment: if `val.contains(filterval)` is false, can there be a single word in val for which its is true?

Comment: @tgdavies yes there can be a single word.

Comment: @xyz16179 They were referring to the fact that if a string doesn't contain `filterval`, no substring (and thus no word within the string) will contain `filterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using streams, it is best not to modify the source of the stream while the latter iterates over the former. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30778017/6117426) for instance.)

Regarding readability and making idiomatic use of stream operations, your code is almost indistinguishable from a plain old for loop (and I would advise you to change it to that if you only use streams to do a `forEach`, but you could modify it to use a chain of shorter and more "atomic" stream operations, as in the following examples.

- To get the list of strings in which at least one word *contains* `filterval`:

  ```java
  List<String> filtered = listArray.stream()
                                 .filter(str -> str.toLowerCase().contains(filterval))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- To get the list of strings in which at least one word *starts with* `filterval`:

  ```java
  List<String> filtered =
        listArray.stream()
                 .filter(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                                      .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                      .anyMatch(word -> word.startsWith(filterval)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```
- To get the list of *words* (in any of the strings) that contain the filter value:

  ```java
  List<String> filteredWords = listArray.stream()
                                      .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                      .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")))
                                      .filter(word -> word.contains(filterval))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

(I'm assuming `listArray`, which you don't show in your code snippet, is a `List<String>`.)

#### Notes

- The condition `val.startsWith(filterval) || val.contains(filterval)` is completely equivalent to `val.contains(filterval)`. The reason is, if a string starts with `filterval`, it must also mean that it contains it; one implies the other.
- There's no need to compute the lowercase versions of single words since you've already lowercased the whole string (so any words within it will also be lowercase).
- Instead of treating single words and space-separated strings separately, we can apply `split` to all of them and then "concatenate" the sequences of words by using `filterMap`.

---

### Minimal, complete, verifiable example

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filterval = "ba";
        List<String> listArray = List.of("foo", "BAR", "spam EGGS ham bAt", "xxbazz");


        List<String> filtered1 = listArray.stream()
                                          .filter(str -> str.toLowerCase().contains(filterval))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> filtered2 =
                listArray.stream()
                         .filter(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
                                              .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                              .anyMatch(word -> word.startsWith(filterval)))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> filtered3 = listArray.stream()
                                          .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                          .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.split(" ")))
                                          .filter(word -> word.contains(filterval))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filtered1.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filtered2.toArray()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filtered3.toArray()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[BAR, spam EGGS ham bAt, xxbazz]
[BAR, spam EGGS ham bAt]
[bar, bat, xxbazz]
```

Comment: this would only output stripped of values. I would need the original values of the list. would need the whole value eg. "spam EGGS ham bAt"

Comment: @xyz16179 My bad. So: you want the list of strings which contain at least one word which contains `filterval`. Correct? (Or do the words have to *start* with `filterval`?)

Comment: the logic that you have coded works fine, the results are just not formatted correctly. You are collecting only the word, would like the whole String instead. Sorry new to streams...

Comment: @xyz16179 I've left all three options in the answer so you can choose the one that suits best.