# Add an element to the list if it doesn't find it with lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I'm filtering an object in a list if the condition is true, if not found it will create and add a new object to the list. But it's not working... could someone help?

```
for (int i = 0; i < questao.getQuestaoOpcao().size(); i++) {                
    questao.getQuestaoOpcao().stream().flatMap(qoi -> qoi.getQuestaoOpcoesIdioma().stream())
            .filter(qoi -> qoi.getIdioma().equals(idiomaSelecionado)).findFirst()
        .orElse(new QuestaoOpcaoIdioma(questao.getQuestaoOpcao().get(i), nomesOpcoesList.get(i), idiomaSelecionado));
}
```

Comment: You are not adding the `b` to the list anywhere, why do you expect this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying Objects within stream in Java8 while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778017/modifying-objects-within-stream-in-java8-while-iterating)

Comment: And how could I add?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)):

```
if (!lista.contains("b")) {
    lista.add("b");
}
```

Consider using a `Set<String>` if you want to prevent duplicates.

Comment: I used the example of a and b to simplify. But I'll change it to what I'm actually trying to do

Comment: If you’re dealing with instances of your own class, you must implement `equals()` (and ideally `hashCode()`) to make this work