# How to modify an element of the Stream based on the value in a HashMap

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I want to overwrite my objects `status` value if a corresponding key/value pair can be found in my `HashMap`.

Sample Model:

```
public class Url {
  private String url;
  private String status;
}
```

```
private List<Url> overwriteStatus(List<Url> myObjects) {
   final var myChecklist = Map.of("www.foo.com", "blocked");

  //if the key exists in `myChecklist`, then overwrite the status
  myObjects.stream().forEach(item -> Optional.ofNullable(myChecklist.get(item.getUrl())).ifPresent(item::setStatus));

  return myObjects;
}
```

My current approach with `Optional`s feels very messy.

What is the best approach to check if the value exists in a `HashMap`, and if so, use that value in a next step?

Comment: you can check if item.url is in myChecklist.keySet(), if it is, then update item.status with myChecklist(item.url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) for the *Stream API* **warns't against** the usage of *stateful streams*.

Functions used in streams has to be **pure**, i.e. don't cause mutations of the *stream elements*, don't modify objects *outside the stream* (that's what basically happens in your code).

Your task can be fulfilled with streams without violating the guidelines mentioned above. For that, instead of changing the state if a new `status` has to be applied, a **new** object  needs to be created.

I also suggest to `Url` objects immutable. So that the same instances could be safely reused in different parts of the application.

```
private List<Url> overwriteStatus(List<Url> myObjects, 
                                  Map<String, String> myChecklist) {

    return myObjects.stream()
            .map(item -> !myChecklist.containsKey(item.getUrl()) ? item :
                    new Url(item.getUrl(), myChecklist.get(item.getUrl())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Immutable** class `Url` (no setters, all fields are `final`)

```
public class Url {
    private final String url;
    private final String status;

    // constructor and getters
}
```

**Note:**

- With regard to the `Optional` type, it was introduced in the **JDK** for only one particular purpose: to represent the return type of methods that could potentially yield `null` and that's it. The practice of utilizing the `Optional` just in order of chaining methods on it is considered to be an **antipattern**.

Comment: 1. This is not a stateful operation. 2. You meant API right ? ;) Not IPA ? :) 3. Why shouldn't you cause mutations of streamed elements ? Is there a good reason *not* to do it ?

Comment: @YassinHajaj `This is not a stateful operation` can you provide a rationale for this statement?

Comment: Alexander, I think he refers to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778017/modifying-objects-within-stream-in-java8-while-iterating - hence I think the setter is safe in this case, if I understood it correctly

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Sure, my bad I should have explained it maybe. This is not a stateful operation because no state is used from outside the `Stream` and used inside the `Stream`. Changing the elements flowing through your `Stream` doesn't make your `Stream` stateful because the previous and next elements are not impacted in any way by the processing of the current element and their environment hasn't changed.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Stream operations must not **interfere with the source** of a stream (take a look at first link in the answer - paragraph **non-interference**).  `myObjects.stream().forEach(o -> o.setSomething())` will interfere with the source. And it must be avoided as well as modifying objects outside the stream.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Also we have a concept of **pure function** which isn't limited to functional programming in Java. By definition, a pure function must not cause modification of mutable reference arguments.

Comment: @TeaCup If we take a look at modification of the property inside the `forEach()` in isolation it might seem to be totally fine because the pipeline will be most likely processed correctly. But it contradicts with the general notion of pure function, because it changes the argument of the function. I mean technically nothing harmful will happen, but it's not aligned the best practices of the functional programming. I don't think that it is a good idea to treat `forEach()` as general purpose operation. If you take a look at the javadoc, it suggests to use this operation with care.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko if you're sending me to a source, at least take the time to read it first. They're talking about the backing datasource, not the elements in it. pure functions don't cause side effects indeed. The "pure function" term does not appear a single time in the documentation you're referencing. I get you're trying to make a point, but it's not a valid one unfortunately.

Comment: @YassinHajaj `"pure function" term does not appear` - So your conclusion is that we can simply blind on the key concept of the functional programming? Documentation is not a tutorial, it's meant to provide a description of expected behavior for any implementation of the JVM. Why would you expect the theoretical notion to be listed in it? You also neglected the issue of shared mutably across the application. Why these objects have to be mutable, at the first place? I don't see any rational for that, unless they are persistence entities.

Comment: Well, `forEach` is one of the only two operations specifically designed to allow operations with side effects (without a side effect, it would be useless). It still has to be used with great care. In this example, it has no interference as long as there are no duplicates in the source list (which is not obvious to the reader of the code). It’s always worth considering whether the intend can be expressed in a different way, not using `forEach`. If not, an ordinary loop might be the better choice. Or using `forEach(…)` on the collection rather than `stream().forEach(…)`.

Comment: @YassinHajaj the relevant part is [in the API specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects). Note that side effects are allowed in the case of `forEach`, but still discouraged. If there’s an alternative without utilizing side effects, it is to prefer.

Comment: @Holger My initial understand of the `forEach` and its sibling `peek` is that they were introduced primarily for debugging purposes and not suitable for production quality code. I've reexamined the documentation, and my attitude towards them doesn't get changed. Does my understanding correct? Seems like everything that could be done by the means of `forEach` can be substituted with loops. Are there any cases when `forEach` will be the most appropriate tool? (apart from debugging and demo-purposes)

Comment: @Holger And can you please explain how duplicated can break this code? I understand if the stream will get turned in to a parallel, threads most likely will not see each other's actions on these objects. And if the status had to be set based on a current status, the result most likely will be incorrect. But it's not the case, the value that needs to be applied is based on the name property and does not change. What can go wrong?

Comment: Using `forEach` directly on the collection is perfectly fine, it’s not different to using a loop. Using it on a Stream may have its places, when the stream logic itself is not expressible as a loop (I once had a case of a variable number of `flatMap` steps) or the source is a stream anyway (e.g. `Files.walk(…)`). When the same object appears more than once, it gets processed more than once, potentially concurrently in case of a parallel stream. Usually without consequences as setters typically consist of just a (atomic) field assignment. But that implies relying on assumptions about internals.

Comment: @Holger Thanks a lot for examples on `forEach`, now that definitely makes sense for me. And I was thinking on how to break this code, I wasn't taking into account that something apart from the assignment might take place. I agree, if setter does some miracles along the way that could break thing in parallel.

Comment: @Holger *I have one more question in regard to this topic:* does the stream from this question has to be considered stateless? If stream statement will be duplicated and executed twice, the result will remain the same. So `forEach` isn't stateful here because it causes predictable side effects, and its execution doesn't depend on a state. Is that correct?

Comment: Whether we can call a function with side effects stateless, is debatable. We can say that the function itself does not depend on the side effects (of previous evaluations), which makes it independent of the processing order, which is a requirement for `forEach`. Which makes it a good fit for `forEach`, but I wouldn’t accept it in any other Stream operation. I don’t know if there’s a good term to describe this behavior.

Comment: @Holger I agree, that's a confusing behavior... Thanks for your clarifications ones again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use a Stream since you are modifying the objects as you are iterating the collection.

Just use a loop

```
for (Url item : myObjects) {
  String status = myCheckList.get(item.getUrl());
  if (status == null) continue;
  u.setStatus(status);
}
```